# QR scanner not working but not getting any errors?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var square: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //creates the session
        let session = AVCaptureSession()

        //Defines the capture device
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video),
                  let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }

        session.addInput(input)



        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        session.addOutput(output)

        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(video)

        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(square)
        session.startRunning()
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects
        metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0 {
            if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
                if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "QR Code", message: object.stringValue,
                                                   preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default,
                                                  handler: nil))
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in
                        UIPasteboard.general.string = object.stringValue
                    }))
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

No errors print out and terminal is also empty. This is my updated version of some Swift 3 code that did work so don't understand why it won't work

Comment: Are you calling `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video)` somewhere?

Comment: New to swift so unsure should I have that in somewhere?

Comment: If you want the user's permission to access the camera, yes. This has nothing to do with Swift as a language, it's a requirement of the AVFoundation APIs, and you would have to make the same call in ObjC, C# or whatever else you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, working fine with me - using Swift 5.2. Modify the function `found()` with whatever you want with the returned string. Reference: [qr scanner](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code)

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func failed() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
        captureSession = nil
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```